# Server variable used in URL Rewrite rule?

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

In IIS, is it possible to get a value for a server variable to use in a URL Rewrite rule condition?

In my applicationHost.config file I have this:

```
  <location path="api.domain-staging.site">
       <system.webServer>
            <aspNetCore>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Staging" />
                </environmentVariables>
            </aspNetCore>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

And I want to add a condition into URL rewrite something like `{HOST_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT} = "Staging"` to be able to determine if the rule is used or not.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is environmentVariables and not server variables. The <environmentVariables> element of the <applicationPools>/<add> element specifies a list of environment variables that Internet Information Services (IIS) 10 will pass to a worker process when an application is launched. The <environmentVariables> element contains a collection of <add> elements which define the individual name/value pairs for each environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are not "[server variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables)"

URL Rewrite rules do not support environment variables, so you might consider [ASP.NET Core URL Rewrite middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0)